# An example of how to plug Monit into Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Any ideas of how to plug in Python with Monit? An example would have greatly helped in documentation.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/monit/0.1

Comment: I don't see why you cannot use the official documentation of Monit plus the very tiny amount of source code there is for the Python API that you have also provided a link to in your question.

Comment: I get this error message when I first try to run the program:

File "monit.py", line 11, in main Failed example: mon[aservice_name].monitored # see also 'running', 'type', 'name' Exception raised: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/lib/python2.7/doctest.py", line 1315, in __run compileflags, 1) in test.globs File "<doctest __main_[3]>", line 1, in <module> mon[a_service_name].monitored # see also 'running', 'type', 'name' NameError: name 'mon' is not defined

Comment: My problem is understanding how to use the XML element in the flow of code: www.diveintopython3.net/xml.html

Comment: Please add such vital information to you post and not in the comment section. Your question mentions neither an error nor the exact problem that you are having. From its current state one can only assume that you haven't read the documentation and are looking for someone to that for you.

Comment: Also provide your full XML code. It seems that you might be using some template from the documentation and haven't replaced the placeholders with actual values (from what I can tell from the small error message snippet you have posted in your comment `mon` seems to be one such place holder).